# XML Element Tree - appending to existing elements and attributes with ET.SubElement()?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, elementtree

I have the following function which builds up a re-usable XML SOAP envelope:

```
def get_xml_soap_envelope():
    """
    Returns a generically re-usable SOAP envelope in the following format:
    <soapenv:Envelope>
        <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body />
    </soapenv:Envelope>
    """
    soapenvEnvelope = ET.Element('soapenv:Envelope')

    soapenvHeader = ET.SubElement(soapenvEnvelope, 'soapenv:Header')

    soapenvBody = ET.SubElement(soapenvEnvelope, 'soapenv:Body')

    return soapenvEnvelope
```

Fairly simple stuff so far.

I was wondering now, would it be possible to append attributes (such as `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`) to the `soapenv:Envelope` element?

And if I also wanted to append the following XML:

```
<urn:{AAction} soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <AUserName>{AUserName}</AUserName>
    <APassword>{APassword}</APassword>
</urn:{AAction}>
```

To the `soapenv:Body` such that I would have something like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    soapenvEnvelope = get_xml_soap_envelope()

    actions = {
        'AAction': 'UserLogin',
    }

    soapAAction = ET.Element('urn:{AAction}'.format(**actions))

    soapenvEnvelope.AppendElement(soapAAction, 'soapenv:Body')
```

So, I could specify a target node and the Element to append to?

Comment: @Tomalak I know this doesn't exist - "something like"

Comment: Not quite, I have `soapenvEnvelope` returned, how do I append to what would have been the `soapenvBody` Element?

Comment: As mentioned, zeep does not like the WSDLs produced by this API. I have tried various clients but they do not work.

Comment: Yes that was a previous question, many thanks.

Comment: Appending to an existing element, I believe you answered it in a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from the bad news: Your function to create the SOAP envelope
(*get_xml_soap_envelope*) is wrong as it fails to specify at least
*xmlns:soapenv="..."*.
Actually all other namespaces to be used should be also specified here.

A proper function creating the SOAP envelope should be somenting like this:

```
def get_xml_soap_env():
    """
    Returns a generically re-usable SOAP envelope in the following format:
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="...", ...>
        <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body />
    </soapenv:Envelope>
    """
    ns = {'xmlns:soapenv': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
         'xmlns:xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
         'xmlns:urn': 'http://dummy.urn'}
    env = ET.Element('soapenv:Envelope', ns)
    ET.SubElement(env, 'soapenv:Header')
    ET.SubElement(env, 'soapenv:Body')
    return env
```

Note that *ns* dictionary contains also other namespaces, which will be
needed later, a.o. *xsi* namespace.

A possible alternative is to define *ns* outside of this function and pass it as
a parameter (your choice).

When I ran:

```
env = get_xml_soap_env()
print(ET.tostring(env, encoding='unicode', short_empty_elements=True))
```

the printout (reformatted by me for readability) was:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:urn="http://dummy.urn"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Header />
  <soapenv:Body />
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Note that this time proper namespaces are included.

Then, to add the *Action* element and its children, define the following function:

```
def addAction(env, action, subelems):
    body = env.find('soapenv:Body')
    actn = ET.SubElement(body, f'soapenv:{action}')
    for k, v in subelems.items():
        child = ET.SubElement(actn, k)
        child.text = v
```

When I ran:

```
subelems = {'AUserName': 'Mark', 'APassword': 'Secret!'}
addAction(env, 'UserLogin', subelems)
```

and printed the whole XML tree again, the result was:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:urn="http://dummy.urn" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Header />
  <soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:UserLogin>
      <AUserName>Mark</AUserName>
      <APassword>Secret!</APassword>
    </soapenv:UserLogin>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```